# How to communicate my bus notification to my odoo 15 frontend?

Tags: notifications, odoo

I am trying to add a notification to my odoo menu any time a object of one of my model is created. In fact the object is an inquiry from the odoo website module. Here is how I've modified or override the create method to generate the `bus object`

```
  # Generate a notification for the internal user
    # Send a message to the custom channel when a new record is created
    channel_name = 'erp_rate.new_quote'
    channel_message = {
        'notification_type': 'new_request',
        'new_request_count': 1,
        # Include any other relevant data
    }
    self.env['bus.bus']._sendone(channel_name, "notification_type", channel_message)
    

    res = super(Inquiry, self).create(vals)
    
    return res
```

As you can see I just sending dummy data to get to the frontend. and here is my plain js code for getting the data.

```
 var BusService = require('bus.BusService');


  // Listen for custom channel messages
  BusService.include({
  start: function () {
      this._super.apply(this, arguments);

      var self = this;
      var channel_name = 'erp_rate.new_qote';
      this.channel_notification = channel_name;
      console.log("channel name", this);
      this.on(this.channel_notification, this, function (message) {
          // Handle incoming message and update the UI
          console.log("we got a new notification for sure", message)
          if (message.notification_type === 'new_request') {
              // Update new request count and other UI elements
          }
      });
  },
```

});
Again the goal is to show updates of the new coming request in the odoo menu.

I have been struggling to make this work for 4 days. And I am even questionning if it is possible to show notifications on the odoo menu. Any help would be highly appreciated.